# Questions About Running time

Tags: c++, big-o

What is the running time in [big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of:

```
vector.push_back(item)
```

and

```
vec.erase(itr)  // itr points in the middle of a vector
```

Comment: What ideas do you have about this? This site doesn't exist to do your homework for you.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it

Comment: well i want to know what is more efficient and why, and if it when the vector gets bigger and smaller if that effects it at all

Answer (score 1):

**O(1)** (amortized time, reallocation may happen) in case of [`push_back()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/)

**O(n)** in case of [`erase()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/) i.e Linear on the number of elements erased (destructors) plus the number of elements after the last element deleted (moving).

Comment: so ammortized means that reallocation may happen?

Comment: "ammortized" is a kind of averaged cost, factoring in the nasty situations... if you add some huge number of elements to the vector, then the number of resizes are typically (but not necessarily) about log_base2(N) - with the copying involved it roughly doubles the work / halves the speed, but O() notation ignores such linear time differences and still considers it O(N).

Comment: what if we are talking about the erase of a linked list? is it the same? or is it O(1) because you dont have to relocate?

Comment: erase from a linked list is O(1), yes. That is, assuming you already know which element should be removed. :)

Comment: @Jon : Its  constant time(amortized) at the beginning or the end, or in the middle.

Comment: @Prasoon: for linked list node removal, it's constant time, not only constant time (amortized) - still a very significant difference if considering worst-case for a single operation.

Comment: does having a double or single linked list make a  difference in this case? thanks everyone!

Comment: @Jon: to erase an element from a singly-linked list you have to change the "next" pointer in the previous element, but in general have no way to get there other than iterating there from the head of the list.  Consequently, it's an O(N) operation.

Answer (score 0):

For "vector.push_back(item)" its only O(1).
And "vec.erase(itr)" O(n) because later elements are shifted down.

Edit: If it points on the middle in the vector, its like O(n/2).

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html:

> A vector is a Sequence that supports random access to elements, constant time insertion and removal of elements at the end, and linear time insertion and removal of elements at the beginning or in the middle.